# Two strings are unequal in while loop - subString problem?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently a little confused by this code that I wrote (it is not the most elegant solution to this problem - please ignore). But I just can figure out why this loop breaks when it says (see snippet) `"h" === "h"`, both values are strings, both values have a length of one & and the same encoding.

I'm sure I'm missing something awfully stupid here but I can't seem to figure it out.

```js
function isSubsequence(checkStr, str) {
    let current = 0
    while (str[current]) {
        if (str[current] === checkStr[0]) {
            for (let i = 0; i < checkStr.length; i++) {
                if (checkStr[i] !== str[current + 1]){
                  console.log("break", checkStr[i], str[current + i], checkStr[i] === str[current + 1], typeof str[current+1], typeof checkStr[i]);
                  break;
                };
                if (i === checkStr.length - 1) return true;
            }
        }
        current += 1;
    }
    return false;
  }
  
  console.log(isSubsequence("hello", "hello world"));
```

Comment: Using `.charCodeAt()` provides different results.

Comment: Your logging `str[current + i]` and checking `str[current + 1]`

Comment: Thanks, @CodeManiac that was the awfully stupid thing I was sure I was missing.

Comment: Why dont you use String.includes() function ?
̀console.log("hello world".includes("hello"))`

Answer (score 0):

> "h" === "h", both values are strings, both values have a length of one & and the same encoding.

This works! 
Take another look at the code, you can see that `if (str[current] === checkStr[0]) {` does it's job and let's you go forward to the `for` loop.
Then you're comparing `(checkStr[i] !== str[current + 1])`.
In this case checkStr[i](i is 0) is *h* and str[current +1](current is 0, but you're adding 1) is *e*.
In your log you're printing:
checkStr[i](i is 0), str[current + i] (current is 0 i is 0) , so you are printing h and h,
**BUT** your're comparing
checkStr[i](i is o) === str[current + 1](current is 0), so you're comparing *h* (checkStr[0]) to *e* (str[1]).